# Multi threaded Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, caching

I am trying to implement custom Cache for C# Portable Library (.Net 4 and higher (Asp.net MVC, Winodws 8 , Widows Phone 8 , Silver light , Might be used for WPF in future) , low latency code, which will be multi-threaded cache , trying to implement on singleton. how can

**How can I make my implementation singleton and thread safe.**

```
interface  ICustomCache
{
    bool IsFound(string key, out value); //returns true if found the object
    void Set(string key, object value); //If there is already an object with such a key, then the set should replace the old object
}


 public class Cache : ICustomCache
    {
       private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _cacheDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
       public bool IsFound(string key, out object value)
        {
            if (_cacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {

                return _cacheDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);

            }
           value = null;
           return false;
        }

        public void SetCachedObject(string key, object value)
        {
            if (_cacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _cacheDictionary.Remove(key);
                _cacheDictionary.Add(key,value);
            }
            else
            {
                _cacheDictionary.Add(key, value);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this as an exercise? If not you can reuse an existing implementation like Guava's LoadingCache. Also, why c# _and_ Java?

Comment: Stack overflow suggested so , it is not exercise, I am implementing for portable library for low latency code

Comment: Well, so far you have an interface. For the implementation: *what have you tried*? Also: portable class library is ambiguous: what frameworks does it need to support? This can be important.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code to make your cache manager singleton and thread-safe

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom cache interface
/// </summary>
interface ICustomCache
{
    bool IsFound(string key, out object value); //returns true if found the object
    void Set(string key, object value); //If there is already an object with such a key, then the set should replace the old object
}

/// <summary>
/// In memory cache implementation
/// </summary>
public class CustomCache : ICustomCache
{
    // use thread safe dictionary
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _cacheDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    public bool IsFound(string key, out object value)
    {
        if (_cacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return _cacheDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        }
        value = null;
        return false;
    }

    public void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        if (_cacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            object dummy;
            if (_cacheDictionary.TryRemove(key, out dummy))
            {
                _cacheDictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _cacheDictionary.TryAdd(key, value);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Cache manager
/// </summary>
public static class CacheManager
{
    private static ICustomCache _cache = null;

    static CacheManager()
    {
        // alternatly use Ioc container like Unity to create the object
        _cache = new CustomCache();
    }

    public bool IsFound(string key, out object value)
    {
        return _cache.IsFound(key, out value);
    }

    public void Set(string key, object value)
    {
        _cache.Set(key, value);
    }
}

// usage
CacheManager.Set("test1", "hello world!");
```

This is a very simple implementation, for completeness you might need to consider adding eviction policy to control the cached object growth/application memory, cache statistics, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Well there lot of assumption and many ways to do, below is just a code snippet jotted down hope gives you some direction:-

```
   interface  ICustomCache
   {
       bool IsFound(string key, out object value); 
        void Set(string key, object value); the set should replace the old object
    }
    public class SQLCustomCache:ICustomCache
    {
        #region ICustomCache Members

        public bool IsFound(string key, out object value)
        {
            "Your Implementation for cheking in SQl";
        }

        public void Set(string key, object value)
        {
            "Your Implementation for Storing it in SQl";
        }

        #endregion
    }
    public class FileSystemCustomCache : ICustomCache
    {
        #region ICustomCache Members

        public bool IsFound(string key, out object value)
        {
            "Your Implementation for cheking  in FileSystem";
        }

        public void Set(string key, object value)
        {
            "Your Implementation for Storing it in FileSystem";
        }

        #endregion
    }
    public class CustomCache
    {
        static ICustomCache mycacheObject = null;

        #region ICustomCache Members
        private CustomCache()
        { 

        }

        public ICustomCache GetCustomCacheInstance(string Type)
        {
            if(mycacheObject==null)
            {
                if (Type == "SQL")
                {
                    mycacheObject = new SQLCustomCache();
                }
                else
                {
                    mycacheObject = new FileSystemCustomCache();
                }
            }
            return mycacheObject;

        }        
    }
```